# UICollectionView with UICollectionFlowLayout not displaying cells in the right location

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView in a test project that I created which does not use Interface Builder. When I run the app the test views that I give to the collection view, via the datasource, are displayed in the the top right corner around (0,0). And I cannot for the life of me figure out why. I have tried adding constraints to the cell's content view. I have also tried messing with the item insets delegate function, but that does not seem to make a difference. Am I missing something?

Here is the code for the test view controller.

```
#import "TestViewViewController.h"

@interface TestViewViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *testViews;

@end

@implementation TestViewViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView {


    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    self.testViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    testLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    testLabel.text = @"I hate collection views.";

    [testView addSubview:testLabel];

    testView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    testLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    testLabel.text = @"I really do.";

    [testView addSubview:testLabel];


    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:self.flowLayout];
    self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];


    NSDictionary *views = @{@"collectionView": self.collectionView};

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[collectionView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[collectionView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionView Datasource
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.testViews.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%i", self.testViews.count);
    [cell.contentView addSubview: self.testViews[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//    UIView *statView = self.testViews[indexPath.row];
    return CGSizeMake(100.0, 100.0);
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For openers the `CGRectZero` macro is the equivalent of `CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)`. It would seem that you'd be in trouble with a definition of the space in which the collection view was to be drawn and the `CGRectZero` origin of `0,0` would put it in the upper left corner of the view.  I tried creating an app with your code - and finally got something to show up when I got the code for `loadView` to look like this:

```
- (void) loadView
{
  self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
  self.testViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  UIView* testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 80)];
  testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

  UILabel* testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80)];
  testLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  testLabel.text = @"I hate collection views.";

  [testView addSubview:testLabel];

  [self.testViews addObject:testView];

  self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 320)  collectionViewLayout:self.flowLayout];
  self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  self.collectionView.delegate = self;
  self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
  self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
  [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
  [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
}
```

The difference being that objects were created with a frame size - that views were added into views and so on.

My thought is that you'd be better off creating your `UICollectionView`in a XIB - setting all the parameters there and also creating a subclass for `UICollectionViewCell` to be able to do more with the contents of the cells as need be.  There's a whole lot more to be done to make this a usable `UICollectionView` with an arbitrary number of cells, but I have to say, the `UICollectionView` is not an easy object to deal with - so I sympathize with you as you come up the learning curve.

Comment: I ended up keeping the CGRectZero, and using [myView  systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height in the sizeForItemAtIndexPath: method in combination with adding a subview to cell.contentView with NSLayoutConstraints in cellForItemAtIndexPath:. Thanks for your suggestion though!